# Make a scrollable text within Divi Builder

Tags: css, wordpress, text, scroll, builder

I have a bar on my website showing "now playing" content.
I need the text to stay in ONE line only.
Whenever the text exceeds a certain amount of pixels (a certain point on the line) it should start scrolling the text.

You can see an example here, made using photoshop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChGPa.jpg

As you can see, the text starts from the "Someone" and then scrolls because it's too long to show.

How can this be done?

See website for reference here:
http://radioglobus.nytsite.dk

Keep in mind that we use Divi from Elegant Themes, running on a Wordpress site.

I've tested with marquee but that doesn't work for us.

Comment: Can u plz add this code in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: What code do you need?
What you see on that image, is made with photoshop :-)